# Ask 10 numbers then add the together

Tags: c#, loops, console, int

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tulos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Anna kokonaisluku: ");
            String Luku = Console.ReadLine();
            int annettu = int.Parse(Luku);
            tulos = laske_pluslasku(annettu);
        }
            Console.WriteLine("Lukujen summa on " + tulos);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int laske_pluslasku(int luku)
        {
            int lasku = 0;

            lasku += luku;

            return lasku;
        }
    }
}
```

The program should ask 10 numbers in a loop and then add them together in "static it". When return the sum and print it.

[I should get a print like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xRr3.png)

My problem is that it won't add all the 10 numbers together. It only displays the last given number. I think that is because of "int lasku = 0;".

Comment: Please read [this meta about non-english code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266581/2060725).

Comment: You need to learn about [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Your add method has `int lasku = 0;` while you should have `tulos += annettu;` in the for loop and forget about that additional method

Comment: Try doing it without the function.  I think that would help.  I can see the issue

Comment: You said that you think it is because of `int lasku = 0`, so you should try something different and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your adding a number to 0 then setting your final variable to the number you just sum.

Change your code to (If you really need to sum it on a method):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int tulos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Anna kokonaisluku: ");
        string luku = Console.ReadLine();
        int annettu = int.Parse(luku);

        tulos = laske_pluslasku(tulos, annettu);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Lukujen summa on " + tulos);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int laske_pluslasku(int tulos , int annettu)
{ 
    return tulos + annettu;
}
```

Or a simplier way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int tulos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Anna kokonaisluku: ");
        string luku = Console.ReadLine();
        int annettu = int.Parse(luku);
        tulos += annettu;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Lukujen summa on " + tulos);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: The first one works just fine after i added "tulos" to tulos = laske_pluslasku(annettu, tulos); Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoniSoininen please use the second way Miguel de Sousa showed you! It is so easier to read and needs less space

Comment: @MartinNiederl I guess he might be learning how to program, and is exploring. Ps thanks edit..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> sumList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Anna kokonaisluku: ");
    String Luku = Console.ReadLine();
    int annettu = int.Parse(Luku);
    sumList.Add(annettu);
}
int result = sumList.Sum();
```